# Redirect not working htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>`
```

But the redirection doesn't seem to happen for any of my `.htm/.html` page

Answer (score 0):

Remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` since it is stopping any existing files to be affected.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|CSS|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [NC,R=302,L]
```

Make sure this is very first rule in your root .htaccess

Comment: I changed the `.htaccess` file to

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [NC,R=302,L]
</IfModule>`

But still the redirection is not working. :-(

I am not very sure, is this problem only with `.htaccess` file, as even I changed something in `index.html` and other existing pages but it not reflected, though I added new pages which are shown properly.

Comment: Further, if I remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, the CSS of my `maintenance.html`doesn't load properly and anyways the other pages are not redirected at all!

Comment: Added a rule to take care of CSS/js issue. Make sure this is your very first rule when you test on s new browser.